# Accelerometer input lag

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, accelerometer

Im using my accelerometer as steering control for my game. The tilt of the iphone determines whether the sprite has a positive, negative or zero velocity. The problem is after a few experiences I start noticing severe input lag. My ships velocity gets modified in the frame update function. I added a print statement before it and saw that it could take up to a few seconds for the velocity to change to match the iphone tilt. This makes the game feel extremely clunky. Why is this happening?

```
if motionManager.isAccelerometerAvailable == true {
            motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!, withHandler:{
                data, error in
                if (data!.acceleration.y) < -0.05 {
                    self.velocity = -500
                }

                else if data!.acceleration.y > 0.05 {
                    self.velocity = 500
             }
                else{
                    self.velocity = 0
                }

            })

        }


override func update(_ currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    moveBG()
    removeBullets()
    print(velocity)
    self.ship.physicsBody?.velocity.dx = velocity
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The input lag is due the fact I haven't set a accelerometer update interval for my motion manager. Setting the value to 0.1 removes my issue and provides smooth gameplay